# jquery removes options from dynamic created content after multiple added rows

Tags: jquery, dropdown

The following issue keeps me busy, can't figure it out why this happens.

I've dynamically created some dropdown menu's which when created should append options that are cloned from the first row which has been static loaded when opening the page. But if I create multiple dynamic rows after the 3th or 4th one the previous menu is getting cleared by jquery?

When hitting the create button again, it's appending the options to the dropdown menu again but now the dropdown menu after the previous one is getting cleared. Does any of you have an idea how this could be prevented.

Im using the following code:

Static data:

```
<tr class="">
<td>
    <input type="hidden" name="items[{{ $i }}][id]" value="{{ $item->id }}">
    <p class="text-black">
        <input type="text" name="items[{{ $i }}][name]" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" value="{{ ((old("items.$i.name")) ? old("items.$i.name") : $item->name) }}" placeholder="item" required>
    </p>
    <p class="small hint-text">
        <input type="text" name="items[{{ $i }}][description]" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" value="{{ ((old("items.$i.description")) ? old("items.$i.description") : $item->description) }}" placeholder="description">
    </p>
</td>
<td class="text-center">
    <input type="text" name="items[{{ $i }}][price]" class="form-control autonumeric" autocomplete="off" value="{{ ((old("items.$i.price")) ? old("items.$i.price") : $item->price) }}" placeholder="price" data-a-dec="," data-a-sep="." data-a-sign="&euro; " required>
</td>
<td class="text-center">
    <input type="number" name="items[{{ $i }}][quantity]" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" value="{{ ((old("items.$i.quantity")) ? old("items.$i.quantity") : $item->quantity) }}" placeholder="quantity" min="1" required>
</td>
<td class="text-center">
    <input type="text" name="items[{{ $i }}][discount]" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" value="{{ ((old("items.$i.discount")) ? old("items.$i.discount") : $item->discount) }}" placeholder="discount">
</td>
<td class="text-center">
    <select name="items[{{ $i }}][tax_id]" class="full-width" data-init-plugin="select2" required>
        @foreach ($taxes as $tax)
            <option value="{{ $tax->id }}" @if($item->tax_id == $tax->id) selected @endif>{{ $tax->rate }}%</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</td>
<td class="text-right">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-remove-item"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
</td>
```

Dynamically added row:

```
$('.table-items > tbody').append('<tr class=""><td><input type="hidden" name="items[' + increment + '][index]" value="' + increment + '"><p class="text-black"><input type="text" name="items[' + increment + '][name]" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" value="" placeholder="item" required></p><p class="small hint-text"><input type="text" name="items[' + increment + '][description]" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" value="" placeholder="description"></p></td><td class="text-center"><input type="text" name="items[' + increment + '][price]" class="form-control autonumeric" autocomplete="off" value="" placeholder="price" data-a-dec="," data-a-sep="." data-a-sign="&euro; " required></td><td class="text-center"><input type="number" name="items[' + increment + '][quantity]" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" value="1" placeholder="quantity" min="1" required></td><td class="text-center"><input type="text" name="items[' + increment + '][discount]" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" value="" placeholder="discount"></td><td class="text-center"><select name="items[' + increment + '][tax_id]" class="full-width" data-init-plugin="select2" required></select></td><td class="text-right"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-remove-item"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button></td></tr>');
```

Executed jQuery to append options:

```
var options = $('.table-items > tbody select:first > option').clone(true);

$('select:not(:has(option))').append(options);
```

Comment: Do you execute the options clone for each new line, or do you do this only once?

Comment: The **var options** will be cloned once the page has loaded. And the append runs each time a new row is added.

Comment: I think this is the problem since you append the very same clone each time to a new element. So jQuery removes it from first and append it to the new. Try to clone the options each time you append them.

Comment: @axel.michel i've changed the clone execution to do it for each new line, and this fixed the problem. :-) thnx!